# Mutiple Choises in Custom Coulmn

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column

I want to create a custom column that has the option to check/mark two or more options.

Example 
Column Name : Sorting_Files:
                    ,Department
                    ,Planning
                    ,Outcoming
                    ,Organizing

So the column has these type of information and I want users to be able to choose multiple options. 
Let's say when they are uploading a file and the metadata window open up and they consider that their file belongd to the Planning type but also Organizing so they check both options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to turn on allow multiple selection checkbox from the column setting. See the screenshot below. This is from the modern UI panel, same option is available via classic UI on edit column page.

[image]